# Can't get the localhost linked to sandbox ip address through hosts

Tags: virtualbox, hosts

I am on Windows 7, I need to copy a file from Windows 7 to the sandbox which is a Linux guest in VirtualBox and has the IP address of `172.18.0.2`

I have hosts file like below:

```
::1 localhost
172.18.0.2 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.18.0.2 sandbox.hortonworks.com sandbox
```

In the Windows command line, I cannot ping to the sandbox by both hostname and IP:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:
1. changed the network from NAT to bridged as below:
[image]

TP_Link is the wireless NIC the Windows host uses for the Internet connection.

running ipconfig result from host is below:
[image]

If I go to:
localhost:1080, I can see the expected page but clicking on the dashboard which is supposed to take me to localhost:8888, it will give me error:

`This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.`

Can you tell me what is the cause and how to fix? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try changing the network type in virtualbox network settings for that particular machine. Check your connection type in virtualbox settings of that particular machine. Try bridge type. .

Comment: I tried bridge just now, even worse, before I can access http://localhost:<port>, now it doesn't open anything, showing `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: Yeah because now it have its own ip. And not the same ip as host So, it cannot be accessed through localhost. You have to use guest os ip to access.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the OP to include some screenshots.

Comment: Did you verifiy on 8888 that particular service is running and no binding exceptions are there?

Comment: Thank you. It is not 8888, it is 8080, typo. I see the service is up and running now and I can access from host. But when I tried to use FileZilla to do some file transfer, `it rejects me: Status: Connecting to 192.168.2.29:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error: Could not connect to server` anything I should do to enable that? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199158/discussion-between-mdivk-and-shivam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the network type in virtualbox network settings for that particular machine. Check your connection type in virtualbox settings of that particular machine. Try bridge type.

Comment: Thank you very much, just a bit supplement here: in Network Connection in Windows host, it is needed to create a `Network Bridge` there.